# image in iframe not reloading/updated after submitting form for 2nd time

Tags: php, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a form at page A with jquery ui button. The form will redirect to page B upon submission which change contrast of image using php gd, save it in server, retrieve it back and then display it in the iframe. 
It works perfectly in other browsers, except IE even after I add this in my code.

```
header('p3p: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTR STP IND DEM"');
```

The image is reloaded with new contrast when I submit form for first time but IE never show the changes if the form is submitted for 2nd time or more with new value. The edited result is successfully saved in the server and show on other browser. It's just not showing it on IE9.

Anyone can help? Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The P3P header will only affect IE if your iframe is depending on cookies and you are trying to use them cross-domain. I do not think your problem is with the cookie privacy policy.

I think you have a caching problem. Try defeating the cache by appending the current time to the image when you reload the iframe, so the URL is always unique. This is one of the easiest ways to guarantee a cache-miss.

```
<img src="your_image.jpg"/>

<!-- Change to: -->
<img src="your_image.jpg?<?php echo time(); ?>" />
```